# How do I USE my google signature once it's made?

Tags: email, gmail, digital-signature, email-signature

There's a million videos on how to make a Gmail signature. Would someone PLEASE just tell me how to include it in an email once it's made. I'm pulling my hair out. Is there an include signature button somewhere, how do I USE my signature?!

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Steps to add signature on your emails:

1. Open your gmail account.
2. Select `Settings` option and click on `General` option
3. Find out  `Signature` option and click on check box under `No-signature` and add your signature and you can also add your link.
   and **DON'T Forget to check mark on** `"Insert this signature before quoted text in replies and remove the "--" line that precedes it."`

[image]

4. After that click on `Save` option
5. Now compose any mail automatically your signature will be displayed.

Hope this helps you.